# Retaining a character string in the vector that doesn't meet strsplit() criteria

Tags: r, string, strsplit

I have different character strings that look like this:

```
t <- c("probable linoleate 9S-lipoxygenase 5 [Malus domestica]", "PREDICTED:  protein STRUBBELIG-RECEPTOR FAMILY 3 [Malus domestica]")
```

I want to remove the 'PREDICTED:' from the character string containing it.

My script looks like this:

```
t <- sapply(strsplit(t, split= ": ", fixed = TRUE), function(x) (x[2]))
```

But, this is the result:
[1] NA                                                       "protein STRUBBELIG-RECEPTOR FAMILY 3 [Malus domestica]"

So, for some reason, it erased t[1], and correctly performed the operation on t[2]. I tried adding grep() to my string:

```
t <- sapply(strsplit(t, if(grep('^*.', t), split= ": " else t, fixed = TRUE), function(x) (x[2]))).
```

I also tried writing a loop:

```
for(i in t){
  if(i == grep('PREDICTED', t[i]) split= ": " else t[i])
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: Why not use [`gsub("PREDICTED:  ", "", t, fixed=TRUE)`](http://ideone.com/GXXaMx)? Or can there be any word before the first `:`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `PREDICTED:` word you may use a simple non-regex `sub`:

```
t <- c("probable linoleate 9S-lipoxygenase 5 [Malus domestica]", "PREDICTED:  protein STRUBBELIG-RECEPTOR FAMILY 3 [Malus domestica]")
sub("PREDICTED:  ", "", t, fixed=TRUE)
```

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/GXXaMx)

If the word before the first colon can be any, use a regex solution:

```
t <- c("probable linoleate 9S-lipoxygenase 5 [Malus domestica]", "PREDICTED:  protein STRUBBELIG-RECEPTOR FAMILY 3 [Malus domestica]")
sub("^[^:]*:\\s*", "", t)
```

See [another demo](http://ideone.com/mNgzlL). Here, `^[^:]*:\\s*` matches 0+ chars other than `:` at the start of the string, then `:` and then 0+ whitespaces (this is matched only once since `sub` is used, not `gsub`.

In both cases, the output is the same:

```
[1] "probable linoleate 9S-lipoxygenase 5 [Malus domestica]"
[2] "protein STRUBBELIG-RECEPTOR FAMILY 3 [Malus domestica]"
```